# How to Union Type react navigation prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

## Union Type react navigation prop?

Hello everyone,

I am using typescript with react-navigation module on react native and I am trying to type a child component Navigation prop that can be used by two different navigations.

My current Navigation structure is a main tab navigator composed with two stack navigator, and screen from both navigator are using the child component that, `onPress` navigate to `MovieDetailsScreen`:

```
├── tabs
│  ├── SearchStack   ├── SearchScreen
│                    ├── MovieDetailsScreen
│ 
│  ├── FavoritesStack├── FavoritesScreen
                     ├── MovieDetailsScreen
```

Here is my current typing for my child component props:

```
type Props = {
  navigation: SearchNavigationProp | FavoritesNavigationProp;
  ...
};

export default function DisplayMoviesList(props: Props) {
  ...

  function _navigateToMovieDetails(id: Id) {
    navigation.navigate('MovieDetails', { id: id });
  }

  return (
...
)
}
```

Both `Stack` possess the `MovieDetails` routes:

```
export type FavoritesStackParamList = {
  Favorites: undefined;
  MovieDetails: { id: Id };
};

export type SearchStackParamList = {
  Search: undefined;
  MovieDetails: { id: Id };
};
```

My problem is in my child component, the line `navigation.navigate('MovieDetails', { id: id });` rise a typescript error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ <RouteName extends keyof FavoritesStackParamList | keyof RootTabParamList>(...args: undefined extends (FavoritesStackParamList & RootTabParamList)[RouteName] ? [screen: ...] | [screen: ...] : [screen: ...]): void; <RouteName extends keyof FavoritesStackParamList | keyof RootTabParamList>(options: { ...; } | { ...;...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem, is there a better way to Union Type in this context ? Or my navigation structure is not correct ?
Except the Typescript error, my app is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to quick fix this problem using User-defined Type Guards:

```
function isSearchNavigationProp(
  navigation: Navigation
): navigation is SearchNavigationProp {
  return (navigation as SearchNavigationProp).navigate !== undefined;
}


export default function DisplayMoviesList(props: Props) {
  ...

  function _navigateToMovieDetails(id: Id) {
    if (isSearchNavigationProp(navigation)) {
      navigation.navigate('MovieDetails', { id: id });
    } else {
      navigation.navigate('MovieDetails', { id: id });
    }
  }
```

However it is not really correct because boths my types possess the `navigate` method so the `else` is actually useless. But TypeScript is happy :).

I've seen similar cases with typescript when mapping union typed object.

If anyone have a better method I am really curious about this .